# Where can I find log after use SandboxPostCopy

Tags: sandbox

After update, I received an email that contained this:

" *"SandboxInit” apex class run finished. Check debug logs for stack trace.* "

Where can I find this log?

Comment: did you try: go to the sandbox / enable debug logs / execute anonymous / run the apex code for sandboxInit ?